# transform minimize weighted sum of absolute value into a linear optimization

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, linearization, convex-optimization, absolute-value

For example, we have an optimization problem

$$
\min \sum_{i=1}^{n} |w_{i} - a_{i}| b_{i} \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i w_i = 0
$$

and $a_i, b_i, c_i$ are given. How to convert it into a linear program?

I know that if we want to minimize $|x - a|$, we should let minimize $z$ where $z \ge x-a$ and $z \ge -(x-a)$. However, in this case, we want to minimize the weighted sum of absolute value and do not know the sign of $b_i$. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: If the given $b_i$ can be negative, the problem is not convex so you cannot formulate as LP.

Comment: if the given bi is negative, we can use the big N method to convert it into a LP, right?

Comment: Big-M constraints involve binary variables, so the resulting problem would be integer linear programming, not LP.

Comment: @Pique, is the problem related to the single/multi-facility location problem? If so, the sign of $b_i$ should be positive and the problem can be formulated as an LP.